# Wrap a wrapfigure and text by a border?

Tags: framed, wrapfigure

Is it possible to wrap a wrappicture with some text nearby by a frame?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not knowing how big the figure and associated text are, it's not possible to give very specific recommendations. You're probably best off (i) keeping the text and (wrap)figure inside a `minipage` environment and (ii) enclosing this minipage in either a [framed](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/framed) or an [mdframed](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) environment. Be sure to "flush" all other pending figures (i.e., those not contained in these nested environments) prior to initiating the framed material, as otherwise the numbering of ordinary figures and wrap-figures will be off.

Here's a MWE that uses the `wrapfigure`, `minipage`, and `mdframed` environments, along with the `lipsum` package for filler text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=red]{mdframed}
\begin{document} 
\noindent
Some text \emph{before} the minipage environment\dots

\bigskip
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\rule{2in}{1in}
\caption{A black rectangle}\label{fig:blackrect}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}

\bigskip\noindent
Some more text \emph{after} the minipage environment\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

**First Addendum**, very kindly provided by @MarcoDaniel: You can use also the package `cutwin`. This way, you don't need to set up `minipage` *or* `wrapfigure` environments, and the positioning is more flexible too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue]{mdframed}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\opencutright
\begin{document} 
\noindent
Some text \emph{before} the mdframed environment\dots

\bigskip
\begin{mdframed}
\def\windowpagestuff{%
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Bildname}
\captionof{figure}{foo}
}
\begin{cutout}{2}{.55\textwidth}{0pt}{12}
\lipsum[1]
\end{cutout}
\end{mdframed}

\bigskip\noindent
Some more text \emph{after} the mdframed environment\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second addendum:** @Herbert raises the point that `cutwin` may not be compatible with the `microtype` package, thereby making the method proposed in the addendum above not as widely applicable as one might/should hope. The "official" version of `microtype` on the CTAN is still 2.4 (early 2010). However, beta-08 of version 2.5 (Sept 2011) is available at [this webpage](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=569); it contains many enhancements and improvements over version 2.4. Version 2.5 of `microtype` is what I have on my system (TeXLive2011), and happily it appears to interact just fine with `cutwin`. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately minipage does not wrap the figure inside it. The figure is placed partly outside the minipage, if the minipage is too small, and so the frame around the minipage does. I would like the frame to wrap the image too.

Comment: @Skip: It would be helpful if you posted a MWE (minimum working example) that provides some information regarding (i) the size of the `figure` to be included and (ii) the amount of text to be included, along with information as to the overall width of the text block. Separately: have you ensured, per the instructions in the user guide of the `wrapfigure` package, that it's not placed in some `list`-type environment?

Comment: @Mico: In order to include the seagull.png in place of your `black rectangle` you need the `\grapicx` package, No?  With `\graphicx` your code worked beautifully.

Comment: @Sony: Thanks for this. Indeed, if the code loaded an image stored in an external file, one would have to use a command such as `\includegraphics` (and, obviously, omit the `\rule` command). As I didn't have the gull image file at hand, I chose to make do with a boring black rectangle for the MWE...

Comment: @Mico: Can I edit your answer to show an alternative?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Absolutely!

Comment: @Mico: Done. Only to show the package `cutout`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks, this is a very neat example indeed! I've modified your code every so slightly, mostly by adding a second image file so that readers can see the effects of using the `cutwin` environment.

Comment: @Mico: No problem. I only want to show an other method. But it isn't really an answer ;-)

Comment: for the left part of text `cutwin` doesn't take the package `microtype` into account, but `wrapfig` does ...

Comment: @Herbert: Please see my added addendum [ha!].

Comment: @Mico: I did _not_ interact with cutwin, the left text part is the same as without `microtype`, which can easily bee seen.

Comment: @Herbert: Your observations make me quite concerned. When I run the second MWE above with and without `microtype` -- again, I have vertion 2.5-beta08 on my system -- there's definitely quite a difference to observe. I wonder what gives?

Answer (score 4):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,lipsum,graphicx,wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\section[Programming block type]{\rnode[lt]{Left}{Programming block type}}
\begin{wrapfigure}[13]{r}%[34pt]% optional argument for an offset into the margin
{5cm} 
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{/tmp/seagull}
\caption[Close-up of a gull]{\rnode[rb]{Right}{Close-up of a gull}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\psframe[linecolor=red,framearc=0.1]%
  ([nodesep=30pt,angle=160]Left)([nodesep=15pt,angle=-10]Right)

\end{document}
```

[image]

if you like it as a coloured rectangle then use

```
\psframe*[opacity=0.1,linecolor=red,framearc=0.1]%
  ([nodesep=30pt,angle=160]Left)([nodesep=15pt,angle=-10]Right)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great with the bonus feature of shading.